# Emitting an Event in Node.js C++ Addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I have an application that reads an array of process data from an industrial controller. I want to push that data to a web page as it changes. To that end, I wrote a node.js addon in c++ that scans the process data and attempts to fire an event when the data value changes. Everything works fine with the Addon until it tries to fire an event, at which point node.js terminates with the error:

```
undefined:0


TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The CPP, javascript shim and test javascript are below. Any insights are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

node_corelink.cpp

```
typedef struct CoreLinkValue
{
    // pointer to a CTS variant value
    CtsVariant* value;

    // copy of the last value that was broadcast
    CtsVariant lastValue;

} CoreLinkValue;


//
// An event structure for pushing events to node.js
// Requires the javascript shim code in node_corelink.js
//
struct Emitter: ObjectWrap 
{
    static Handle<Value> New(const Arguments& args);
    static Handle<Value> DataChange(const char* topic, CtsVariant* value);
};

//
// Create a message payload based on the variant type and
// initiate sending out on the topic
//
static Handle<Value>
createVariantHandle(CtsVariant* value)
{
    Handle<Value> ret;

    switch (value->type)
    {
    case CTSTYPE_BIT:
    case CTSTYPE_BYTE:
        ret = Integer::New(value->value.byte[0]);
        break;

    case CTSTYPE_WORD:
        ret = Integer::New(value->value.word[0]);
        break;

    case CTSTYPE_DWORD:
        ret = Integer::New(value->value.dword[0]);
        break;  

    case CTSTYPE_WORD64:
        ret = Number::New(value->value.word64);
        break;

    case CTSTYPE_REAL64:
        ret = Number::New(value->value.real64);
        break;

    default:
        ret = Undefined();
        break;
    }


    return ret;

}


Handle<Value> Emitter::New(const Arguments& args) 
{
  HandleScope scope;

  assert(args.IsConstructCall());
  Emitter* self = new Emitter();
  self->Wrap(args.This());

  return scope.Close(args.This());
}


// emits DataChange Event
Handle<Value> Emitter::DataChange( const char* topic, CtsVariant* value ) 
{

  HandleScope scope;

  Handle<Value> argv[3] = {
    String::New("DataChange"),  // event name
    String::New(topic),             // topic argument
    createVariantHandle(value)      // value argument
  };


  printf ("C++ Emitting event!\n" );

  MakeCallback(context_obj_, "emit", 2, argv);
  return True();

}



//
// Triggered by the event loop on a regular interval.
// Scans the registered data to see if the latest value has been
// broadcast and does so if needed.
//
void
scan_task( uv_timer_t* timer, int status )
{

    std::map<std::string, CoreLinkValue>::iterator it;
    bool doUpdate;

    for(    it = pdos_.begin();
        it != pdos_.end();
        ++it )
    {
        if (forceRefreshPdos_ == true)
        {
            //
            // An update of this value was requested.
            //
            doUpdate = true;
        }
        else if ( it->second.value->type != it->second.lastValue.type )
        {
            //
            // If the types don't match, then this variant was obviously
            // updated.
            //
            doUpdate = true;
        } 
        else if ( it->second.value->value.word64 != it->second.lastValue.value.word64 )
        {
            //
            // Word64 contains all bits of the value. If this value has
            // changed, then they've all changed.
            //
            doUpdate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            doUpdate = false;
        }

        if (doUpdate)
        {
            it->second.lastValue.value = it->second.value->value;
            Emitter::DataChange( it->first.c_str(), it->second.value );
        }

    }



    if (forceRefreshPdos_)
    {
        forceRefreshPdos_ = false;
        printf("Completed refresh all.\n");
    }       

}



//
// Start the execution of the scan loop
//
int
startScanLoop( void )
{
    uv_timer_init( uv_default_loop(), &scanTimer_ );
    uv_timer_start( 
        &scanTimer_,    // timer instance
        &scan_task,         // callback function
        0,              // startup delay    (ms)
        100 );          // repeat interval (ms)

    return 1;
}


//
// Stop the execution of the scan loop
//
void
stopScanLoop( void )
{
    uv_timer_stop( &scanTimer_ );
}


//
// Connects to the kernel IPC 
//
Handle<Value> 
connect(const Arguments& args) 
{
    HandleScope scope;


    ...

    startScanLoop();

    return scope.Close( True() );
}


//
// Shuts down the kernel IPC 
//
Handle<Value> 
close(const Arguments& args) 
{
    HandleScope scope;

    stopScanLoop();

    ...

    return scope.Close( True() );
}

//
// Called by node.js to initialize the library.
//
void 
init(Handle<Object> target) 
{

    target->Set(String::NewSymbol("connect"),
        FunctionTemplate::New(connect)->GetFunction()); 

    target->Set(String::NewSymbol("close"),
        FunctionTemplate::New(close)->GetFunction());   


    //
    // Events interface
    //
    Local<FunctionTemplate> t = FunctionTemplate::New(Emitter::New);
    t->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
    t->SetClassName(String::New("Emitter"));

    target->Set(String::NewSymbol("Emitter"), t->GetFunction());    


}

NODE_MODULE(node_corelink, init)
```

node_corelink.js

```
module.exports = require(__dirname + '/build/Release/node_corelink.node');

var Emitter = require(__dirname + '/build/Release/node_corelink.node').Emitter;
var events = require('events');

inherits(Emitter, events.EventEmitter);
exports.Emitter = Emitter;

// extend prototype
function inherits(target, source) {
  for (var k in source.prototype)
    target.prototype[k] = source.prototype[k];
}
```

test.js

```
process.stdin.resume(); //so the program will not close instantly
process.on('exit', function () {

    corelink.close();
    console.log('Goodbye!');

});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  console.log('Got SIGINT.');
  process.exit();
});


var corelink = require('./node_corelink');
var Emitter = require('./node_corelink').Emitter;

var e = new Emitter();

e.on('DataChange', function(s) {
  console.log('DataChange');
});


corelink.connect();
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to trigger callback in a less-graceful method.

node_corelink.js

```
module.exports = require(__dirname + '/build/Release/node_corelink.node');
```

test.js

```
var corelink = require('./node_corelink');

function onDataChange( topic, value )
{
    if ( value !== undefined )
        console.log ( topic + " ::: " + value.toString() );
}

function onMessage( msg )
{
    console.log ( "Message from kernel: " + msg.toString() );
}

corelink.connect(onDataChange, onMessage);
```

node_corelink.cpp

```
static void 
dataChange( const char* topic, CtsVariant* value ) 
{

    HandleScope scope;

    Handle<Value> argv[2] = 
    {
        String::New(topic),         // topic argument
        createVariantHandle(value)      // value argument
    };

    MakeCallback(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), pfOnDataChange_, 2, argv);

}



static void 
onMessage( const char* message ) 
{

    HandleScope scope;

    Handle<Value> argv[1] = 
    {
        String::New(message)            // message argument
    };

    MakeCallback(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), pfOnMessage_, 1, argv);
}


//
// Connects to the kernel IPC 
//
Handle<Value> 
connect(const Arguments& args) 
{
    HandleScope scope;

    if ( args.Length() < 2 
        || !args[0]->IsFunction()
        || !args[1]->IsFunction() )
    {
        return scope.Close( False() );
    }

    pfOnDataChange_ =  Persistent<Function>::New(args[0].As<Function>());
    pfOnMessage_ = Persistent<Function>::New(args[1].As<Function>());

    ...



    return scope.Close( True() );
}
```

Comment: Where did MakeCallback come from?

Comment: MakeCallback is a part of node.js. See the node.h header.